# Changing Event Arguments while Executing

Tags: node.js, events, twitter, discord, discord.js

I am currently developing a Discord Bot focused on sharing Twitter Tweets to Discord Channels, coded in Node JS and using npm module Twit for Twitter API.

Twit, basically creates a stream event, that occurs everytime one of the users from the IDs Array Tweets Something and then a `.on` with the tweet information defined as `tweet`.

```js
stream = twitterClient.stream('statuses/filter', { follow: followArray })


stream.on('tweet', tweet => {

})
```

The `followArray` is the Array containing the Users IDs, defined like: `followArray = ['3083945176', '34507480']`

However, if I want to add or remove an ID from the Array, I would have to restart the Bot, instead of being able to just `followArray.push(userID)`. How could I update the Array without having to restart the Bot?

Comment: why don't you make a function inside `message` event which takes the `id` you mention in the message and add\remove that from the `followArray`. I'm not familiar with this Twitter API but I think to update your `followArray` you need to also put this stream var(not the listener) inside a `message` event so that you can update it later.

Comment: about the part of taking the id of a twitter user from his username and add it do followArray I already know how to do, the problem is update the stream with new followArray, without having to restart the bot.